# Avoid Login popups when JQuery loads content with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, http-authentication

I have a index.html which loads 3 blocks of content using 3 different `$.load(...)` queries. 
When I use basic http authentication , the login and pass is requested 4 times. 1 on the page load, and 1 for each content.

How can I keep the login up, WITHOUT passing it on the `$.load url?` (for security purpose).

```
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="maindiv"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#header").load("?cmd=header");
        $("#maindiv").load("?cmd=viewconfig");
        $("#footer").load("?cmd=footer");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by HTML authentication?

Comment: my bad, i meant basic http auth. I will fix it.

Comment: the client has no control of said popup. javascript can't make it stop.

Comment: use a more advanced authorization system. Note also there are global ajax methods that would allow setting request headers for all requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the response to a *401 http status code* instead of the *Authorization http header*. Then you can catch these responses and show your own login dialog popup.

In my example, all JQuery Ajax call result statuses are checked for the *401 code* and the first occurrence will show the dialog:

```
var loginFormShown = false;
$.ajaxSetup({
  statusCode: {
    401: function(xhr) {
      if(!loginFormShown) {
        console.log('Show login form popup', xhr.responseText);
        loginFormShown = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header").load("?cmd=header");
    $("#maindiv").load("?cmd=viewconfig");
    $("#footer").load("?cmd=footer");
});
```